# Nginx fails with "104: Connection reset by peer" when Gunicorn returns a 500

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I am running Django with Gunicorn (19.6.0) behind Nginx (1.6.2). Everything works fine with one small problem.
If I send a POST request with a JSON payload larger then about 10KB and Django replies with a 500er I get a `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` in Chrome and the response is empty, although Django is sending a JSON string `{"error":"some error description"}`.

Nginx log shows a `104: Connection reset by peer`:

If the payload of the POST request is small, I get the expected result. 
If I send the same request (also with large payloads) directly to gunicorn no error happens and I do get the expected response.

My Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    location /static/ {
    root /srv/yyyyy;
    }

    location /media/ {
    root /srv/yyyyy;
    }

    # Proxy Pass to Gunicorn
    location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/srv/yyyyy/proxy_pass.sock;
    }
}
```

I also tested with a `proxy_buffering off;` in the location block, but still same result.

Comment: have you tried this ? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size, they say the size is usually 8k on x86_64 which I assume you're using. Maybe you can try to increase this value.